# What is the right way to make a neural network learn a period function with known period

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning

I want a neural network to learn the representation of a periodic function whose period is known to be $T$.

What is the correct way to achieve that? From my reading, I could infer two things:

1. This [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.08195) proposes using an activation function of form $x + sin^2(x)$.
2. The above paper mentions that we can use *fourier features* when the period is known. However, I could not find any good reference of what does *fourier features* exactly mean.

Can someone please explain or point to a resource that can explain how to incorporate fourier features into a NN?

Comment: Is there only one input variable? Or multiple variables, only one of which defines the space that the output repeats over? Do you have a strong requirement of continuity over the $T \rightarrow 0$ boundary?

Comment: Multiple variables, only one of which defines the space that the boundary repeats over. No requirement of continuity over the mentioned boundary